# Colorear un campo si se encuentra vacío

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Estoy mostrando en una tabla los registros de usuarios. Quiero que me coloree un campo de rojo si cualquiera de los campos se encuentra vacío. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Éste es el código que tengo en PHP para generar mi tabla:

```php
<?php

while($mi_fila=mysqli_fetch_array($datos)){
    $id=$mi_fila['id'];
    $nombre=$mi_fila['nombre']; //pintar este campo de rojo
    $foto1=$mi_fila['foto1'];
    $foto2=$mi_fila['foto2'];
    $email=$mi_fila['email'];
    $documento=$mi_fila['documento'];

    if($foto1=="" || $foto2=="" || $email=="" || $documento==""){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$id ."</td>";
        echo "<td id='rojo'>".$nombre ."</td>";
        echo "<td> <img src='storeFiles/$foto1' width='150px'</td>";
        echo "<td> <img src='storeFiles/$foto2' width='150px'</td>";
        echo "<td>".$email ."</td>";
        echo "<td> <img src='storeFiles/$documento' width='150px'</td>";
        echo "</tr>";          
    }
}

?>
```

¿Necesito JS para completarlo? ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? No tengo mucha idea.

Comment: No deberías dar el mismo id a elementos que se crean en bucle. En vez de esto: `<td id='rojo'>` puedes usar una clase: `<td class='rojo'>` y luego por `.css` aplicas el color rojo a los `td` de la clase `rojo`.

Comment: [_El atributo global **id** define un identificador único (ID) el cual no debe repetirse en todo el documento._](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Comment: Tampoco estás cerrando la etiqueta de las imágenes, que puede create algunos problemas graves cuando se muestre el contenido (y el `width` debería ser un entero sin unidades).

Comment: No me había dado cuenta del cierre del img, gracias! Y no acabo de entender lo del width sin unidades, width='150' a secas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arriba de tu validación podrías inicializar una variable que será el color del campo que quieres pintar:

```
$color = "";
```

Luego validamos que si se cumple la condición, la variable será lo siguiente:

```
if($foto1=="" || $foto2=="" || $email=="" || $documento==""){
    $color = "color: red;";
}
```

Y por último, el siguiente código:

```
echo "<td id='rojo'>".$nombre ."</td>";
```

Cámbialo por:

```
echo "<td style='".$color."'>".$nombre ."</td>";
```

De esta forma, si encuentra vacíos en uno de tus campos, se cumplirá la validación, la variable será `"color: red;"` y esto estará en el style.

---

También, ten en cuenta lo que te dicen en los comentarios, hay que ser muy cuidadoso con el cierre de las etiquetas y el uso de los `id`.

Comment: Al final le he metido un style en el td: echo "<td style='background-color:red'>".$nombre ."</td>"; aunque no se si es mejor como dices de declarar la variable fuera y luego llamarlo. Gracias a todos!!

Comment: @kblc Recuerda verificar la respuesta marcándolo con un ✔️ para que tu pregunta esté como respondida. Claro, la variable tiene que estar dentro del while.

Comment: ¿dónde lo verifico? soy nuevo en esto